# Cohomology of constant sheaf Z on circle S1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider sheaf cohomology defined by derived functor, which means use injective resolutions of sheaves to define cohomology group. Now, if Z is the constant sheaf of group of integers on unit circle S1 with its usual topology. How to computer the first cohomology group of Z on S1?

Comment: One can calculate this easily enough from a fine resolution, but are you really insisting on using an injective resolution.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes. You must use injective resolution or long exact sequence. Pure algebra.

Comment: @raisinsec if a proof using a resolution which is not by injectives would satisfy your curiousity, you may find one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305031/hartshorne-exercise-iii-2-7a-sheaf-cohomology-of-constant-sheaf-bbb-z-on/4305517#4305517).