# Hartshorne Exercise III.2.7(a): sheaf cohomology of constant sheaf $\Bbb Z$ on $S^1$ in the usual topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $S^1$ be the circle(with its usual topology), and let $\mathbb Z$ be the constant sheaf $\mathbb Z$
>
> (a) Show that $H^1(S^1,\mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z$, using our definition of cohomology.

I have tried to construct an injective resolution: like Proposition 2.2, Let $I^0=\prod_{x\in S^1}j_*(\mathbb Q)$. But then I don't know how to  calculate its stalk. So I have difficulties in build the $I^1$... If I just use its discontinuous sections to build a flasque resolution, I also can't calculate the stalk...

Could you provide some help or give a complete answer? Using Cech cohomology is also accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to compute a full resolution of $\Bbb Z$ - a short exact sequence is enough to solve the problem if you're clever about it.

Let $\def\cF{\mathcal{F}} \def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}} \def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \def\cQ{\mathcal{Q}} \def\G{\Gamma} \def\coker{\operatorname{coker}} \cF$ be the flasque sheaf which assigns to each $U\subset S^1$ the set of all functions $U\to\RR$.
Embed $\ZZ\to\cF$ in the obvious way and let $\cQ$ be the quotient.
Taking the long exact sequence in cohomology arising from $$0\to \ZZ\to \cF\to \cQ\to 0,$$ we note that $H^1(S^1,\cF)=0$ implying $H^1(S^1,\ZZ)=\coker(\G(S^1,\cF)\to\G(S^1,\cQ))$.
By exercise II.1.3, any section $s\in\G(S^1,\cQ)$ is the image of a family $\{(s_i,U_i)\}_{i\in I}$ with $s_i\in\cF(U_i)$ where $U_i$ form an open cover of $S^1$ and $(s_i-s_j)|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ is a section of $\ZZ_{U_i\cap U_j}$.
Since $S^1$ is compact, we may assume $I$ is finite; after subdividing, throwing away redundant elements, and reordering we may assume that our cover consists of connected open subsets so that $U_i$ only intersects $U_{i-1}$ and $U_{i+1}$ with indices interpreted modulo $|I|$.

Now I claim that it suffices to consider $|I|=3$.
Let $n_{i+1}$ be the value of $s_{i+1}-s_i$ on $U_i\cap U_{i+1}$.
Replacing $s_{i+1}$ with $s_{i+1}-n_{i+1}$, which does not change the image of $s_{i+1}$ in $\cQ(U_{i+1})$, we see that $s_i=s_{i+1}$ on $U_i\cap U_{i+1}$.
Therefore we can glue $s_i$ and $s_{i+1}$ to form a section of $\cF$ over $U_i\cup U_{i+1}$ without changing its image in $\cQ$.
Repeating this process for $i=3,\cdots,|I|-1$, we see that we can glue the sections $s_i$ on $U_3\cup\cdots\cup U_{|I|}$ so that we're only looking at $\{(s_1,U_1),(s_2,U_2),(s_3,U_3\cup\cdots\cup U_{|I|})\}$.

If we have a section $\{(s_1,U_1),(s_2,U_2),(s_3,U_3)\}$, by the same logic we may assume that $s_1=s_2$ on $U_1\cap U_2$ and $s_2=s_3$ on $U_2\cap U_3$.
Therefore up to adding a global section of $\cF$, the global sections of $\cQ$ are exactly those of the form $\{(0,U_1),(0,U_2),(n,U_3)\}$ for $n\in\ZZ$ and opens $U_i$ satisfying our ordering and intersection assumptions.
Since any two such sections are equivalent up to an element of $\G(S^1,\cF)$ iff their $n$s match, we see that the cokernel is exactly $\ZZ$.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Cech cohomology

Take the open cover $U_{up} \cup U_{down}$ of $S^1$ where $U_{up}$ covers a bit more than top half of circle, and $U_{down}$ covers a bit more than bottom half of circle, both $U_{up}, U_{down}$ are connected. Note that $U_{up} \cap U_{down} = U_{east} \cup U_{west} $ is then a disjoint union of two connected open intervals, around "East" and "West" pole of the circle.

Cech cohomology means you want to compute the cohomology of this complex:
$$0 \to C^0 = \mathbb{Z}(U_{up}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}(U_{down}) \to C^1 = \mathbb{Z}(U_{up} \cap U_{down}) \to 0$$
with restriction map being $(a,b) = b-a$.

Now note that

- for any open $U$, $\mathbb{Z}(U)$ is locally constant $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions on $U$. When $U$ is connected, this forces $\mathbb{Z}(U)$ to be constant functions on $U$.

  - This means $\mathbb{Z}(U_{up})$ and $\mathbb{Z}(U_{down})$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. This also means $\mathbb{Z}(U_{up} \cap U_{down}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, corresponding to the constant value on the "east" piece and the "west" piece respectively.
- The Cech cohomology sequence is then
  $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
  where the middle map is $(a,b) \to (b-a, b-a)$. It's then clear that $H^1(S^1, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. (since kernel is everything, image is those where two coordinates are equal)